# duplicate based on a set of values in a list

Tags: java, sorting, collections

I have a List of VO, need to find duplicate entries based on values?

```
name usageCount numberofReturns trendNumber nonTrendNumber trendType
Name1   0           0              1           1             A
Name2   0           0              1           1             B
Name3   0           0              1           2             C
Name4   0           0              2           2             D
Name5   0           0              2           2             E
```

Current trend = "X"
In this list i have to find out duplicate values using usagecount, numberofreturns, trendNumber and nonTrendnumber. Here (Name1 ,name 2) and (Name4,name5) are same, so i have to update the trendType value = X and leave Name 3 as it is.
Is there any alternate way other then iterating the list with for loop and update the list value using CopyOnWriteArrayList(to avoid concurrent exception)?

Comment: Why would changing an objects data inside of a list cause a `ConcurrentModificationException`? You don't change the lists direct contained objects, just the objects data.

Comment: @Smutje Thanks for the information, Is there any alternate way doing this logic other than for loops?

Comment: Someone obviously has to loop through a list to find any duplicates, whether it is your code directly or a library method - the bigger problem in your case is that you have to match every row with every other row to check for duplicates as duplicates only are defined between rows and not globally based on certain constant values.

Comment: You have to iterate collection at least once, to know the data it contains. So, question should be: is it possible to do, what you want, with just a one iteration.

Answer (score 0):

This list of VO objects is populated by you? If yes than you can implement the **equals, hashCode** methods in the VO class. You can implement these methods according for that fields that are you want to be unique (usagecount, numberofreturns, trendNumber and nonTrendnumber). After that you can **replace the List with Set** and voile the set will not contains any duplicates.

If the List of VO objects isn't populated by you than another solution is to iterate through the list and insert in a **Set**. The VO2 class is the same DTO class as VO but has implemented the **equals and hashcode** methods.